# Joining same table does not return expected results

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a table with fields and data as below.

```
appid     determid      empid   empchargeperc 
1          14           79        1.0
1          15           71        0.42
1          16           70        0.04
1          16           71        0.41
1          16           79        0.13
```

What i want is based on last 2 determination id (15 and 16 in above table) i want to get all the employer ids (empids) as per below 3 conditions.

1. get all empids which are present in old determid (15) and not in new determid (16). Output: None
2. get all empids which are present in new determid (16) and not in old determid (15). Output: empids: 70, 79
3. compare employer charges percentage (empchargeperc) for same employers for old and new determid and if it changed, return the employer. As per above table there is just one empid 71 for determ 15, so that would be compared to empid 71 of determid 16 and as 0.42 <> 0.41, that employer would be returned as well.

So i want to return empids 70, 71, 79. I wrote below query and i get expected output.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.appid, a.empid
FROM dbo.emp a JOIN dbo.emp b ON b.appid= a.appid
WHERE a.determid IN (SELECT TOP(2) determid FROM dbo.determ 
WHERE appid = @appid ORDER BY createdate DESC) AND 
a.empchargeperc <> b.empchargeperc
```

But not correct output for below table. Empids i get is 47 and 81 but i expect no empids should be returned as for determids 30, empid 47's empchargeperc matches determid 45's empid 47's empchargeperc. Same for empid 81.

```
appid     determid      empid   empchargeperc 
1          11           47        0.16
1          11           81        0.83
1          30           47        0.16
1          30           81        0.83
1          45           47        0.16
1          45           81        0.83
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

From the description of your conditions, this sounds like aggregation with a `having` clause:

```
select empid
from (select d.*, dense_rank() over (order by determid desc) as rnk
      from determ d
     ) d
where rnk <= 2
group by empid
having min(determid) = max(determid) or
       min(empchargeperc) <> max(empchargeperc);
```

Comment: If i run above, i get errors: Invalid column name 'empid' and 'empchargeperc'. You have not used emp table and those columns are in that table. Could you please update check your query. Thanks

Comment: @chrismasters . . . "I have a table with fields and data as below."

Answer (score 1):

You can do complex stuff clearly with CTEs -- below I've done step 1 and 2 using this technique as an example

```
WITH NEW_D AS
(
  SELECT MAX(determid) as determnd
  FROM dbo.determ 
  WHERE appid = @appid
), OLD_D AS
(
  SELECT MAX(determid) as determid
  FROM dbo.determ, NEW_D
  WHERE appid = @appid AND determid <> NEW_D.determid
), EMP_NEW AS
(
  SELECT empid
  FROM emp, NEW_D
  WHERE appid = @appid AND determid = NEW_D.determid 
), EMP_OLD AS
(
  SELECT empid
  FROM emp, OLD_D
  WHERE appid = @appid AND determid = OLD_D.determid 
)
SELECT empid
FROM EMP_OLD
WHERE empid NOT IN (SELECT empid FROM EMP_NEW)

UNION ALL

SELECT empid
FROM EMP_NEW
WHERE empid NOT IN (SELECT empid FROM EMP_OLD)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It is giving me error where on the line "  WHERE appid = @appid AND determid <> NEW_D.determid" inside OLD_D.

Comment: maybe because I left off the ")" -- did you put that in?

Comment: Yes i did and was still getting the error. Invalid column name 'determid'. Is it just because you are using aggregate function with Where clause?

Comment: @chrismasters -- I had the wrong table name in the CTE -- I changed it.